# Symfony2 difference between path

Tags: symfony, remember-me

I have to setup a remember me login with my Symfony2 project and I have to setup my firewall in security.yml

I did something like that

```
        remember_me:
            secret: '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800
            path: ^/
```

I was wondering what is the difference between **/** and **^/** for the path parameter ?

Comment: The `path` parameter at the end of the day is used as `path` parameter for [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.setcookie.php) function used to create "rememberme" cookie. `^/` makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment, this is now clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine your url is this one : https://example.com/

`^/` <=> catch all path that start with "/"

`/` <=> catch all path that are preceded by "/"

So in this case there is no difference, both are matching all path after the last "/" of https://example.com/

In your case, you have to put "/" instead of "^/" because "^/" makes no sense in this context.

According to the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html) :

> path (default value: /)
>
> The path where the cookie associated with this
> feature is used. By default the cookie will be applied to the entire
> website but you can restrict to a specific section (e.g. /forum,
> /admin).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html). The relevant passage quotes:

> Prepending the path with ^ means that only URLs beginning with the
>   pattern are matched. For example, a path of simply /admin (without the
>   ^) would match /admin/foo but would also match URLs like /foo/admin.

Comment: This fragment of documentation refers to `access_control.path` which takes a regular expression, not cookie parameter which is a simple string.